# Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found - Upgrading Angular to Version 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

I am upgrading my apps from Angular v11 to Angular v12. I have this error when I try to upgrade Angular packages:

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12
```

```
Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found 

Package has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0" (extended), would install "12.0.0").
Package has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0" (extended), would install "12.0.0").
```

Those are just warnings, but migration has failed because of them.

I can choose to use the `--force` option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and address these warnings later. Should I do that? If I do that will that break the packages that have incompatible peer dependencies?

Comment: Yes it is possible that the external packages you're using won't function properly. Do check whether your project libraries have Angular 12 support

Comment: can you include more info, like what dependencies are incompatible in your case ?

Comment: I added it. Only `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` library is showing, but I don't know is that because upgrading will stop after discovering first incompatible peer dependency, or is this the only one.

Comment: Isn't there some trace other than this one line Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found?

Comment: Yeah, the list of incompatible packages, but I didn't include that in question because it is project related.

Comment: You may be missing an error like in this particular case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285869/incompatible-peer-dependencies-found-upgrading-angular-from-8-to-9. So thought to ask about stack trace. Some more data in log like -  (requires ">=3.4 < 3.6", would install "3.7.5").???? or anything

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I updated my question. The problem is that peer dependency is incompatible with `@angular/common` and `@angular/core` .

Answer (score 34):

I was facing the same problem and this are the steps I took to resolve

1. Ensure your node version is greater than 10
2. Run `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`. You are most likely to receive an error like below

```
Package "@angular-eslint/builder" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cli" (requires ">= 11.2.0 < 12.0.0", would install "12.0.0").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\KOTIENO1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-gY5FIE\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The warning advices that we can use `--force` to ignore the warnings. We will do that for now
3) Run `ng update`. This will return all commands we need to run

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 68 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                                    Version                  Command to update
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular-eslint/schematics              4.2.0 -> 12.0.0          ng update @angular-eslint/schematics
      @angular/cdk                            11.2.11 -> 12.0.0        ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                            11.2.11 -> 12.0.0        ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                           11.2.12 -> 12.0.0        ng update @angular/core
      @ngrx/store                             11.1.1 -> 12.0.0         ng update @ngrx/store

    There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
    You can update the additional packages by running the update command of your package manager.
```

4. Run `ng update @angular-eslint/schematics @angular/cdk @angular/cli @angular/core @ngrx/store --force`. This is per the step 3, yours may be slightly different. Remember to add `--force` flag

This successfully runs with a a number of warnings

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: furaha-app@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: @angular/compiler-cli@12.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm WARN   @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@angular-devkit/build-angular, @angular/localize, ng-packagr)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: furaha-app@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: typescript@4.2.4
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   typescript@"4.2.4" from the root project
npm WARN   4 more (@angular-devkit/build-angular, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@"~4.2.3" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: furaha-app@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: @angular/compiler@12.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm WARN   @angular/compiler@"~12.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@angular/compiler-cli, @angular/localize, ng-packagr)
```

5. By this step your `package.json` file has been updated. Run `ng serve` to make sure everything is working as expected
6. Check the warnings. Most will be related to compatibility as most angular related packages expect  verson 10 <= @angular/core <12. This can be handled by case to case basis e.g updating these packages

Comment: Yeah, I used the `--force` option. I had problem with 3rd party packages that expected lower version than 12.

Comment: Wonder why do they not mention these things in the "[Official Angular Migration Guide](https://update.angular.io/)". What is the purpose of such a Guide if you still end up here to make things work...