# Trouble when updating the project from angular 8 to angular 15

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular8

I am trying to update an angular project from 8.3.26 to any version after 12, I understand that it should be version by version. So I'm trying to update to angular 9, but as soon as I start following the guide in the documentation : https://update.angular.io/

This command `G_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 --allow-dirty` 
peer dependency errors start popping up:

```
`                  Package "angular-notifier" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">= 6.0.0 < 7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "angular-notifier" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">= 6.0.0 < 7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "ng2-ckeditor" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^9.0.2" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.26", would install "0.9.1").
✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "/tmp/ng-ROUCuS/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.26
Node: 18.13.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.0.0
```

These are the packages and their versions currently installed :

```
`Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.26
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.26
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.26
@angular/animations               8.2.14
@angular/cdk                      14.0.0-next.2
@angular/cli                      8.3.26
@angular/http                     8.0.0-beta.10
@angular/material                 14.0.0-next.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.26
@schematics/angular               8.3.26
@schematics/update                0.803.26
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.39.2`
```

I tried a solution found here : [Incompatible peer dependencies found - upgrading Angular from 8 to 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285869/incompatible-peer-dependencies-found-upgrading-angular-from-8-to-9)

where it says change the versions of the packages in package.json to thee "would install" versions, then hit npm install, this one gave me the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ey-csirt@4.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"8.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0-0 || ^15.1.0-0 || ^15.2.0-0 || ^15.3.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@15.2.0-next.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"github:angular/cdk-builds" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/mohamed/.npm/_logs/2023-01-17T13_10_40_742Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mohamed/.npm/_logs/2023-01-17T13_10_40_742Z-
```

Deleting node modules and package-lock.json doesn't work, when I delete them and hit npm install again, conflicting dependency errors pop up and the command doesn't work. I've read somewhere that the best option is to redo the project from scratch on a new template from the desired version but this will take forever and I'm tied to a deadline

debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the versions of angular-notifier,ng2-ckeditor,angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker compatible to your @angular/common, @angular/forms, @angular/core.
Please refer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier?activeTab=versions for version details.